# Big.Int Div always returns 0

Tags: go, multiplication, biginteger, bigint

I am unable to get a value when using BigInt.Div() in Go.

Big Ints:

```
    totalAllocPoint, _ := instance_polypup.TotalAllocPoint(&bind.CallOpts{}) //*big.int
    fmt.Println("totalAllocPoint: ", totalAllocPoint)// 54000

    poolInfoStruct, _ := instance_polypup.PoolInfo(&bind.CallOpts{}, &pid) //*big.int
    fmt.Println("allocPoint: ", poolInfoStruct.AllocPoint)// 2000
```

I have tried to divide using the following code, always returns 0:

```
    poolInfoStruct.AllocPoint.Div(poolInfoStruct.AllocPoint, totalAllocPoint)
    fmt.Println("poolAlloc: ", poolInfoStruct.AllocPoint)
```

```
    poolAlloc := big.NewInt(0).Div(poolInfoStruct.AllocPoint, totalAllocPoint)
    fmt.Println("poolAlloc: ", poolAlloc)
```

```
    poolAlloc := big.NewInt(0)
    poolAlloc.Div(poolInfoStruct.AllocPoint, totalAllocPoint)
    fmt.Println("poolAlloc: ", poolAlloc)
```

Comment: If you want rationals use Rat instead of Int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Int.Div()`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.Div) is an integer division operation. And you divide `poolInfoStruct.AllocPoint` by `totalAllocPoint` which is `2000 / 54000`. That will always be `0`, because the divisor is greater than the dividend.

Maybe you want the opposite? `totalAllocPoint / poolInfoStruct.AllocPoint`

See this example:

```
totalAllocPoint := big.NewInt(54000)
allocPoint := big.NewInt(2000)

totalAllocPoint.Div(totalAllocPoint, allocPoint)
fmt.Println(totalAllocPoint)
```

Which output `27` (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XCzjMm-tLGz)).

You indicated that divisor and dividend are correct. If so, you cannot use `big.Int` for this, as `big.Int` can only represent integers.

You may use [`big.Float`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Float) for this for example, and use [`Float.Quo()`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Float.Quo) to calculate the quotient.

For example:

```
totalAllocPoint := big.NewInt(54000)
allocPoint := big.NewInt(2000)

tot := big.NewFloat(0).SetInt(totalAllocPoint)
ap := big.NewFloat(0).SetInt(allocPoint)

tot.Quo(ap, tot)
fmt.Println(tot)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Mpi6yKBTzX6)):

```
0.037037037037037035
```

Another option is to use [`big.Rat`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Rat) and [`Rat.Quo()`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Rat.Quo):

```
tot := big.NewRat(0, 1).SetInt(totalAllocPoint)
ap := big.NewRat(0, 1).SetInt(allocPoint)

tot.Quo(ap, tot)
fmt.Println(tot)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mmpJrghn0ZT)):

```
1/27
```